# Is there a way to stop the auto sorting of the columns when using JOIN clause

Tags: vb.net

I'm setting up this datagridview with lots of data from different data tables so I used JOIN. However, the datagridview seems to display the columns in order of the table.

This is my code:

```
 Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
            conn.Open()
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblclientprofile LEFT JOIN tblbusinessinfo ON tblbusinessinfo.B_IdNo = tblclientprofile.IdNo 
                                            LEFT JOIN tblownerprofile ON tblownerprofile.O_IdNo = tblbusinessinfo.B_IdNo
                                            LEFT JOIN tblbusinessprofile ON tblbusinessprofile.BP_IdNo = tblownerprofile.O_IdNo
                                            LEFT JOIN tblbusinessoperations ON tblbusinessoperations.BO_IdNo = tblbusinessprofile.BP_IdNo
                                            LEFT JOIN tblbfs ON tblbfs.BF_IdNo = tblbusinessoperations.BO_IdNo
                                            LEFT JOIN tblcapitalstructure ON tblcapitalstructure.IdNo = tblbfs.BF_IdNo
                                            LEFT JOIN tblassetsize ON tblassetsize.IdNo = tblcapitalstructure.IdNo
                                            LEFT JOIN tblsaleshistory ON tblsaleshistory.IdNo = tblassetsize.IdNo
                                            LEFT JOIN tbldomesticmarket ON tbldomesticmarket.IdNo = tblsaleshistory.IdNo
                                            LEFT JOIN tblexportmarket ON tblexportmarket.IdNo = tbldomesticmarket.IdNo
                                            LEFT JOIN tblprodservline ON tblprodservline.IdNo = tblexportmarket.IdNo
                                            ", conn)
                With cmd
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                End With
                Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Using dt As New DataTable
                        da.Fill(dt)
                        dgv2.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

tblclientprofile has fields such as: IdNo, Status, Name, Position, etc
tblbusinessinfo has fields such as: BusinessRegNo, BusinessName, BusinessType etc.

datagridview's results is IdNo, Status, Name, Position, BusinessRegNo, BusinessName, BusinessType in order.

What i want is to display this in order of: IdNo, Name, Position, BusinessRegNo, BusinessName, BusinessType, Status

Comment: Then stop using `SELECT *` and list the column names in the order in which you want them to appear. If you don't tell the datagrid what order you want them to appear in, why would you expect it to be in any order other than the order it finds them in in the table?

Comment: If you want the columns in a specific order then stipulate that in your SQL code, i.e. write out your column list explicitly rather than using a wildcard. Alternatively, you can add the columns to the grid yourself rather than letting the grid do it automatically, or you can reorder the columns after they are created. The former would be done in the designer and then setting the `DataPropertyName` to specify what source column to bind to. The latter would be done by setting the `DisplayIndex` of each column.

Comment: Thank you guys. Can you give me a link where I can learn more about what you guys are talking about>

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution to the columns being out of order is to add this loop that sets the `DisplayIndex` to the `Index`. Put this loop right after your call `dgv2.DataSource = dt`

```
For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgv2.Columns 
    col.DisplayIndex = col.Index
Next
```

The `Index` is assigned to each column as they are added. I'm not sure why the `DisplayIndex` becomes out of order, but the above script will fix it.

Also, I'd like to point out that this has nothing to do with the SQL. This is the result of something going on in the DataGridView. With that said, you should still select your columns instead of using *.